# Rails 5, simple javascript with form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I am hoping someone can help me here. Been at this for a few hours, but can't seem to figure out why my Javascript is not working on my simple form. I'm simply trying to display comments using the ajax call. I have gem 'jquery-rails', and required jquery, and jquery_ujs in my application.js file. Here's the code I have so far:

I have a Joy model that has_many comments.

```
<% @joys.each do |joy| %>

<ul id="comments-<%= joy.id %>">
  <% joy.comments.where(void:'f').each do |comment| %>
    <li><%= comment.body %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= form_with(model: [ joy.user, joy, joy.comments.build ], data:{ "js-comments-#{joy.id}" => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, :class=>'form-control', :required=>'true' %>
  <%= f.submit "Post Comment" %>
<% end %>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-js-comments-<%= joy.id %>]').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
      $('#comments-<%=joy.id%>').append(xhr.responseText);
    });
  });
</script>

<% end %>
```

In my Comment controller, in my 'create' action, I have:

```
if @comment.save
  render partial: "comment", locals: {comment: @comment}
end
```

In my Comment views, I created a partial, called _comment.html.erb:

```
<li>
    <%= comment.body %>
</li>
```

So, now when I enter a comment, and click 'Post Comment', it correctly saves my Comment, but it does not ajax load the comment into list. Furthermore, the form does not refresh either. The text remains in the text box. It is not only until after I refresh the page when my comment shows up in the list. Anyone with any thoughts on what I'm missing or doing wrong???

Your help is greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: @jvillian I don't believe so.

Answer (score 0):

`form_with` it's a remote form, you dont need that block `<script>..</script>`.
Just use `create.js.erb` then use jquery to append new comment.

And if you want to check if your message was created successfully, you can add a @status value in your controller.

> ```
> //comments_controller.rb
> def create
>   ...
>   if @comment.save
>     @status = "success"
>   else
>     @status = "failed"
>   end
>   ...
> end
>
> //create.js.erb - for example
>  $("#yourCommentList").append('<%= j( render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: @comment ) %>');
>  <% if @status == "success" %>
>    $("body").append(...your notification...)
>     ...
>  <% else %>
>     ...
>  <% end %>
> ```

Comment: Hi @Dapeng114 - I tried this, but still not able getting the comment to populate. Now, I'm getting a POST javascript error when I try to run it.