# ajax rails form_with submits but only after page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've had an existing comment form on a resource `show.html.erb` that I want to be added to the show page without having to reload the entire page.  I understand that with ajax via the 'form_with' form, this should be entirely possible.

My issue is that whilst the form does create a new comment, it only appears after I refresh the page.

I also get the following error.

> ArgumentError (too few arguments):
>
> app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:18:in 'format'
>   app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:18:in 'create'

**comments_controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_commentable
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :comment_auth, only:  [:edit, :update, :destroy]

...

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(allowed_params)
    @comment.user_id=current_user.id if current_user
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment added." }
      format.js
    else
      render 'edit'
    end

...
```

**views/comments/create.js.coffee**

```
comment = document.getElementById("comment")
comment.innerHTML = "<%= j render(@comment) %>"
```

**views/comments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: [@commentable, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Please correct the following errors.</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <strong><%= f.label :name, :class=>'form-label' %></strong><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, value: current_user.fname, readonly: true, :class=>'form-control' %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong><%= f.label :title, :class=>'form-label' %></strong><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :class=>'form-control' %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong><%= f.label :review, :class=>'form-label' %></strong><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body, :class=>'form-control', rows: 5 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit :class=>'btn btn-success' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I needed

```
<%= form_with(model: @message, method: :post, local: true) do |f| %>
```

local: true was necessary. All other combos didn't work remote: true, remote: false, local: false

Answer (score 0):

as you know, `form_with` it's a remote form, you should not use `redirect_to` there. Please remove your block

> ```
> if @comment.save
>   format.html { redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment added." }
>   format.js
> else
>   render 'edit'
> end
> ```

replace it to

> ```
> if @comment.save
>   @status = "success"
> end
> ```

And you can add a notice message to your `views/comments/create.js.erb` (it's not .js.coffee) with condition of @status (failed/success).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That has resolved the too few arguments issue, thanks.  However, I still need to refresh the page to show the new comment. Any ideas how I can fix that?

Comment: @SimonCooper did you try my suggestion above? 
This is the same with your question, i think
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480899/rails-5-simple-javascript-with-form-submit/49489134#49489134

Comment: yes I did the replacement as you suggested.  I will take a look at that other question, thanks.